# Error using double.parseDouble and JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, parsing, double, joptionpane

I'm trying to put the answer in a variable but I get stuck in this error:

```
    double p1;

    String text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type the grade of p1");
    p1 = double.parseDouble(text);
```

when i use the `double.parseDouble(text)` I get `"double cannot be dereferenced"` in the Netbeans ID.E

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the class name with a capital `D`:

```
p1 = Double.parseDouble(text);
```

The [`parseDouble` method is in the `Double` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29).  If it's lowercase, that refers to the primitive type `double` which generates your compiler error.